# Joint CDF in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Computing a CDF (Cummulative Distribution Function) in numpy is fairly straightforward, but now I want to move to multiple dimensions using the 3 dimensions of data and then compute be able to easily compute the corresponding X, Y, Z for say Nth percentile easily.

I'm finding the documentation out there is not the easiest to navigate and that would be useful. I'm trying to use what is already out there and not re-invent the wheel.

Here is how I do it in 1D:

```
h, x = np.histogramdd(np.array(full_data), bins = 10, normed = True)
dx = x[1] - x[0]
f1 = np.cumsum(h)*dx
```

Then plot:

```
plt.plot(x[1:], f1)
```

In 3D it will look like:

```
full_data = [[1,2,4], [2,3,4], ...]
```

Any suggestions for something more pythonic and elegant before I cludge something together.

Comment: have a look at [kernel density estimation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) method, it works in n-dims

Comment: Not clear what "the Nth percentile" means for vector-valued samples. Say, X and Y are uniformly distributed over [0, 1] and we want the 50th percentile. Where would that be and why?

Comment: I agree with @user6655984, in 2D or 3D how are you going to do that `cumsum`? Matplotlib has a 2D histogram but I don't know of a 3D histogram function, so you will have to go with kernel density estimation, but the problem remains how you define a percentile in >1 dimension.